# prevent nginx Docker container from exit

Tags: docker, nginx, kubernetes, devops

I have an nginx container and a php-fpm one.
I use K8S and both containers are in the same pod.
I want to configure nginx timeout or something similar to wait for the upstream.

This is my config:

```
server {
server_name mywebserver;
root /myapp;

location / {
    try_files $uri /index.php$is_args$args;
}

location ~ ^/index\.php(/|$) {
    resolver 127.0.0.1 valid=30s;
    fastcgi_pass myapp:9000;
    proxy_connect_timeout 120;
    proxy_read_timeout 120;

    fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.*)$;
    include fastcgi_params;



    fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $realpath_root$fastcgi_script_name;
    fastcgi_param DOCUMENT_ROOT $realpath_root;
    internal;
}

location ~ \.php$ {
    return 404;
}

error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;
access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;
```

}

I added:

```
proxy_connect_timeout 120;
proxy_read_timeout 120;
```

but it seems that it's not working.
Is there any reliable solution for this ?

Answer (score 0):

```
resolver 127.0.0.1 valid=30s;
fastcgi_pass myapp:9000;
```

Hardly makes any sense, just go for 127.0.0.1, unless you want to loadbalance between `myapp` backends, in which case, it is counterintuitive to keep them in the same pod, you should then use a php-fpm as separate backend deployment and service